# Select from localStorage

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using angularJS. I'm trying to build a select menu in HTML which will be populated by names that are stored in the local storage under `$localStorage.users.names.`

I have had a look online but can't seem to find anything other than -

`<select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in $localStorage.users.name">{{ x }}
    </option>
    </select>`

But this doesn't populate the menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the users from local storage in controller and use that in view file.

In your controller -

```
$scope.users = $localStorage.users;
```

In your view -

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in users">{{ x.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `$localStorage` in `$scope` to be able to access it like you're doing. Like so:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$localStorage = $localStorage;
    // The rest of your code...
});
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to make the localStorage object available to the template?

Something like that:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage
){
    $scope.localStorage = $localStorage;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$localStorage = $localStorage;
});
```

and html should be use `get()` function to retrieve the local storage value. like below

```
ng-repeat="x in $localStorage.get("users").name
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot use `$localStorage` inside `HTML`.

So assign `$localStorage.users.names` into your `$scope` variable.

**Controller**

```
$scope.userNames = $localStorage.users.names;
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="userName in userNames">{{ userName }}
    </option>
</select>
```